# How to run maven plugin from console

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm developing maven plugin

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.breedish.cfit</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-cfitautomator-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
<name>cfitautomator</name>
```

But how i can run it from console?
if i run com.breedish.cfit:maven-cfitautomator-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:run-goal it is always saying:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Cannot execute mojo: run-goal. It requires a project with an existing pom.xml, but the build is not using one.
```

Comment: Looks like you are running your mvn command from the wrong directory. Make sure you are in the same directory as your pom file and run it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a deep look at the [maven-invoker-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/) which can support you in developing Maven plugins with integration tests with environment etc. So you don't need to manually install that plugin and test it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not running this command in a directory which contains a pom file.

It says it needs a POM file.

Answer (score 0):

Install your plugin to local repository using `mvn install`. Then use it as you posted.